# Make my border triangle responsive

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is a triangle using CSS borders.

It's currently set to 500px width. however I want to make it take up the full width of the screen while maintaining its triangular pointy shape

https://jsfiddle.net/hra17z5t/1/

```css
#one {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 300px;
}
#two{
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  border-right: 250px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  border-left: 250px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;    
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Comment: You can't do that with borders as they do not take a % value. you might have to re-think. Perhaps SVG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have [updated your code example](https://jsfiddle.net/hra17z5t/4/): since you wanted to make it responsive to the full browser width, it's pretty straightforward:

```css
#one {
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 300px;
}

#two {
    border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-right: 50vw solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50vw solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Here we're simply setting the box's width to `100vw`, which is 100% of the browser width. Since the dimensions of your triangle respond in the same way, based on your example you can simply set the border widths to `50vw` (or half the browser width), and it will grow and shrink responsively.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  var divWidth = $('#one').width();
    $('#two').css({
      borderLeftWidth: divWidth / 2,
      borderRightWidth: divWidth / 2
    });
});

$(window).trigger('resize');


#one {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hra17z5t/10/)

Answer (score -1):

Found this on Google when searching "Responsive CSS Triangle"

https://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/3HG6d/

Relevant code is below:

```
/*Down pointing*/
.triangle-down {
    width: 10%;
    height: 0;
    padding-left:10%;
    padding-top: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle-down:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left:-500px;
    margin-top:-500px;

    border-left: 500px solid transparent;
    border-right: 500px solid transparent;
    border-top: 500px solid #4679BD;
}
```